# Reset an row selections on page load within material react table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-react-table

Using [Material React Table V1](https://v1.material-react-table.com/) is there a prop perhaps within initialState to ensure that on page load of any table, ensure that no rows are selected.

I have something like this:

`import { MaterialReactTable } from 'material-react-table';`

```
      <MaterialReactTable
        key={refreshPage}
        columns={myTableColumns}
        data={myTableContent}
        enableColumnResizing
        enableFullScreenToggle={false}
        enableHiding={false}
        enablePinning={!isMobile}
        enableExpanding
        enableStickyHeader
        enableRowSelection
      />
```

I basically want to be able to reset any row selections whenever the table is loaded on page load.

I tried to look out for something like:

`table.toggleAllRowsSelected(false)` on page load but I don't have access to `table`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `initialState` prop combined with a `selectedRowIds` property set to an empty object. This will effectively initialize the table with no rows selected.

```
import { MaterialReactTable } from 'material-react-table';

<MaterialReactTable
  key={refreshPage}
  columns={myTableColumns}
  data={myTableContent}
  initialState={{
    selectedRowIds: {}, // This will ensure no rows are selected initially
  }}
  enableColumnResizing
  enableFullScreenToggle={false}
  enableHiding={false}
  enablePinning={!isMobile}
  enableExpanding
  enableStickyHeader
  enableRowSelection
/>
```

Comment: unfortunately this did not work. Sorry, what exactly is `selectedRowIds` here? I was also wanting to see if there was also a means of looping through all the rows of the table and if checkbox: checked then uncheck it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else comes across this issue/requirement using material-react-table V1, I managed to solve this as follows:

```
const [selection, setSelection] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
    setSelection({});
}, [myId]);

<MaterialReactTable
  key={refreshPage}
  columns={myTableColumns}
  data={myTableContent}
  enableColumnResizing
  enableFullScreenToggle={false}
  enableHiding={false}
  enablePinning={!isMobile}
  enableExpanding
  enableStickyHeader
  enableRowSelection
  onRowSelectionChange={setSelection}
  state={{ selection }}
/>
```

The inclusion of `onRowSelectionChange` and `state={{ selection }}` solved my issue.

More info can be found here: [State options](https://v1.material-react-table.com/docs/guides/row-selection#access-row-selection-state)